# LAN devices are not accessible in python script when user is not logged on

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, networking, operating-system

I am encountering a very strange issue, never faced this before I wrote a python script to check every 5 minutes if set of IP addresses are available & responding by pinging them. The script is working fine, and I use a CRON job to do this periodically. The script is following.

```
import subprocess

def ping_ip(ip_address):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(['ping', '-c', '1', ip_address], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, timeout=5)
        if result.returncode == 0:
            return True, result.stdout
        else:
            return False, result.stderr
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        return False, "Timed out"

def main():
    ip_addresses = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.249"]

    for ip in ip_addresses:
        is_responding, response = ping_ip(ip)
        if is_responding:
            print(f"{ip}\tResponding")
        else:
            print(f"{ip}\t Not Responding")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is whenever a user login to the device using SSH, the IP addresses are always responding & accessible but after closing the SSH connection, The IP addresses are no longer accessible e.g., not pingable.

Operating System Details:

- Nvidia Xavier
- Ubuntu 20.04

**Note: Those addresses stay inaccessible unless a user again SSH into the device.**